# Can you get "Session Quality" via the reporting API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I know there are some examples of data that you can get through the Analytics UI but not through the reporting API, like the User Explorer view.

After digging around a little I have failed to find session quality in the metrics and dimensions -- is this another example of data that is available in the Analytics UI but not in the reporting API? Or is it under another name and I just haven't looked for it the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all the possible reporting API metrics and dimensions are listed at [Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) so if something is not there then something is not available within API requests . And session quality dimensions and metrics seems not to be there :(

Comment: Occasionally I have found the metric with enough digging -- under a different name. In this case, I didn't see anything, but I thought I'd confirm. ;)